# zgrep : transform string to regex to speed up line searching

Tags: regex, bash

I'm writing a script in bash shell and I'm using `zgrep` for file searching. The problem is that it takes too much time to run this command for my 50GB of log files :

```
zgrep "from=$name" file | zgrep "PROCESSED_EVENT=true" | zgrep "mediaFrom=0"
```

where `$name` is a variable that I read from a text file. All three patterns are in the middle of each log entry.

I'm thinking of replacing this binary search by regular expression, but I'm not familiar with regex. Could anyone give me some idea?

Comment: `egrep "from=$name.*PROCESSED_EVENT=true.*mediaFrom=0"`?

Comment: @amow Thanks I'll give that a try to see if it works

Comment: `grep -e` = `egrep`, just add `-e` to zgrep